# Why covariance in data constructor

Tags: scala

I have following trait definition:

```
sealed trait Option[+A]
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

the `Option` type is covariant but why do `Some[+A]` is also covariant too?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from the answer? As the question stands, the only answer is "Because the author defined it this way".

Comment: What I od not understand is, why `Some[+A]` needs covariance ? When I define a variable like `val l = Some(3434)` then A is a type of Int. I can not see any point the need of covariance.

Comment: @zero_coding Why do you think it is not needed?  Do you know what covariance means?  With covariance `Some[B] <: Some[A]` if `B <: A`.  Without covariance Some[B] and Some[A] would be unrelated types regardless of the relationship between A and B

Comment: Why would be happen, if I would change to `Some[A]`? Can you please show me some example?

Comment: It allows you to do: `val s: Some[Any] = Some(3434)`

Comment: Please more example, it need more to the aha effect. Thanks

Comment: `Some[+A]` and `Option[+A]` don't "need" to be covariant. The are covariant because the author of that code (you?) chose to make them covariant. One is making `Option` covariant, the other is making `Some` covariant (they are 2 distinct types). The author could have chosen to make only one of them (or neither) covariant.

Comment: The example is from https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/errorhandling/Option.scala